SQL Grouping and Nested Concatenation
Sample data :



ID
Continent
Country
City




1
Africa
Egypt
Cairo


2
Africa
Egypt
Alexandria


3
Africa
Egypt
Luxor


4
Africa
Morocco
Rabat


5
Africa
Morocco
Casablanca


6
Asia
China
Beijing


7
Asia
China
Shanghai



The output I need is :



ID
Continent
CountryAndCities




1
Africa
Egypt(Cairo,Alexandria,Luxor) - Morocco(Rabat,Casablanca)


2
Asia
China(Beijing,Shanghai)



I tried this code:
SELECT DISTINCT
    Country,
    ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT CONCAT('- ', City)
                  FROM Continental s2
                  WHERE s2.Country = s.Country
                  GROUP BY City
                  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''), '') AS Cities
FROM
    Continental s
GROUP BY
    Country

I get the following output:



Country
Cities




Egypt
Cairo- Alexandria- Luxor


Morocco
Casablanca- Rabat


China
Beijing- Shanghai



How can I get my desired output (shown above)?

What version of sql-server are you on?

@ P.Salmon :  why does continent not appear in your query when your desired outcome wants it? because i couldn't , i don't know how to add continent and get the desired output. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise version 15

Try this:
with cities as (
    select Continent, 
       Country + '(' + string_agg(City, ',') + ')' as Cities
    from continental
    group by Continent, Country
)
select 
    row_number() over (order by Continent) ID,
    Continent,
    string_agg(cities, ' - ') CountryAndCities
from cities
group by Continent
order by Continent

See it work here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/G2XJX6jE

This uses string_agg(), which does require at least SQL Server 2017. So it's possible if you're running SQL Server 2016 (or SQL Server 2014, which is supported for just less than another two weeks ) you may need to do something else. If you have anything older, it's time to upgrade.
